# Regexp to extract Spanish (maybe non-English) words in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, unicode

What's in a word? Or better, what's a word?
So far I had been using character groups to extract words from text. Original text is in markdown, so working with words is maybe better than tokenizing them. Besides, working with words eschews any kind of markup, so it's more general. I'm using [this text](https://github.com/JJ/Test-Text/blob/master/text/es/texto.md) as a test.
Before adding that text to the test suite, I was using this regexp:

```
our $word_re = qr/([\w\'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑçÇüÜ]+)/
my ($stripped_word) = ( $w =~ $word_re );
```

It pretty much worked for English with some Spanish words thrown in. But then I tried Spanish and I had to add

```
 ($stripped_word) = ( $stripped_word =~ /([^¿!ªº\d]+)/ ); #Some Spanish sigils and digits
```

to take care of left punctuation marks and some more stuff. 
The general problem is even if this works for English and Spanish (so far), it's a hack and it might not work for Icelandic or Czech or Dalmatian. So I have tested regexen including Unicode character classes, but this is the result:

```
x ( "¿Más o menos?" =~ /(\p{Word}+)/g )
0  '¿'
1  'Má'
2  's'
3  'o'
4  'menos'
```

which, as you can see, marks as "word" character the left question mark, and what baffles me the most, "á" as a end-of-the-word character. Of course, the plain `\w` is not much better

```
 x ( "¿Más o menos?" =~ /(\w+)/g )
0  'M'
1  's'
2  'o'
3  'menos'
```

So, the final question is: is there a (preferably short) regex that is able to extract words in a (reasonable) amount of languages? Or the best approach is to first extract word-like stuff using enumeration of characters in the languages you're interested and then strip them of the stuff that is actually *not* a real character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined in [perlunicode - Unicode character properties](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties), to extract words that only contain letters of any language use:

```
\b\p{L}+\b
```

---

If the words also contain digits use:

```
\b[\p{L}\p{Nd}]+\b
```

Comment: Thanks. Works with the string, but not with a file. That was not the question, however.

Answer (score 2):

From **man perlre**:

> A `\w` matches a single alphanumeric character (an alphabetic
>   character, or a decimal digit) or `_`, not a whole word. Use `\w+` to
>   match a string of Perl-identifier characters (which isn't the same as
>   matching an English word). If "use locale" is in effect, the list of
>   alphabetic characters generated by `\w` is taken from the current
>   locale. See `perllocale`.

P.S. Dont forget the `use utf8` directive and related stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This works on your example:

```
use utf8; 
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "¿Más o menos?";

my @fields = $str =~ m/(\p{Word}+)/g;

foreach my $f(@fields) {
    print $f, "\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Close, but no cigar. `perldoc utf8` says explicitly `Do not use this pragma for anything else than telling Perl that your script is written in UTF-8.`. That means that if you read the text from a file, it will not work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: In that case, open the file with the proper :encoding http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html